# jquery mouse gestures/btn queuing

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am using jquery super gestures, http://www.evanbot.com/article/super-gestures-jquery-plugin/22, for an interface on a site.

I want each gesture I use to have a series of actions assigned to it e.g:

- When one movement (say moving the mouse to the left) is performed by the user it fades in a div with a nice graphic prompting the user to do something else
- When the same movement is performed it fades in a different div forgetting about the last action it performed for that movement.

This could go on and on until it runs out of actions for that particular movement. I would then apply this to a whole series of mouse movements up, down , left, right, circle, zig-zag etc

My question is, how do i get jQuery to move through a series of actions in this manner?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want associate the same event to a queue of actions? For each call to the event the an action is dequeued and performed? Do you need to do anything more complicated than put some action performing functions to a list and forward the event call to these functions in the gestures callback-function?

Comment: @Aleksi Essentially yes. I would eventually like to somehow record what actions/functions the user has performed and have that data remembered by jquery so the interface can call on previous actions and appear to be more intelligent. But for now I would like to learn how to achieve the above, hopefully this is relatively. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript arrays to hold the queue of actions to be performed

```
var queue = [];

queue.push(function() { 
   alert('hello world') 
}); 
queue.push(function() {
   alert('goodbye cruel world');
});
```

Then, when the gesture is performed you can use

```
...
callback: function(gesture) {
   if(0 == queue.length) {
       ...
   } else if('circle-clockwise' == gesture) {
       var fn = queue.shift(); // get the first element in queue
       fn();
   }  
   ...
} 
...
```

to call the next action in queue.

Note: You can write the function call as queue.shift()(); as well if you want to be shorter.

Comment: Thanks Aleksi I'll try and figure this out.